# How to find date after certain period in php

Tags: php, date, yii

I am working in yii framework. i am getting current date in php (Yii framework) by-

```
$date =new CDbExpression('NOW()');
```

Its giving date in format-"2013-04-27 12:49:27".
I want to find date after one year. So how to find date in this format after one year or certain period in php?

Comment: `strtotime("2013-04-27 12:49:27");` will give you a timestamp. `strtotime("+1 year", $timestamp);` will give you a timestamp of +1year from that date. `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);` will format it back again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+365 days"));
```

Comment: thanx sir for reply. Actully i want to perform date comparison.          $date=new CDbExpression('NOW()');
strtotime($date);                                             $expirydate= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+90 days"));                    i want to check wether current date is less than the $expirydate. So how to perform this comparison

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to manipulate with dates in php.

```
$newDate = new DateTime($date);
$newDate->modify('+1 year');
echo $newDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**[DEMO.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zWK7sY)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use alternate which look like this:

```
$date =new CDbExpression('NOW()');
$NextYear = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date)) . " + 365 day"));
```

If you want more specific you can try:

```
$date =new CDbExpression('NOW()');   
$NextYearDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 year',$date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this

```
$date = new CDbExpression('NOW() + INSTANCE 1 YEAR');
```